# get error when trying to show message box in function called from thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, qmessagebox

I am trying to show message box in pyside python in function called from thread but I got error " Fatal IO error: client killed" and form closes while it shows correctly if I called function normally without thread

code for button click when defining the thread

```
mythread = Thread(target=self.main_campaign)
mythread.start()
```

the function as below

```
def main_campaign(self):
    QMessageBox.question(self, 'title', 'text', QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
```

Comment: can you add the whole error stack trace?

Comment: are you using a Python thread object or a QThread? Using a QThread can solve your problem.

Comment: from threading import Thread

Comment: QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python2.7: ../../src/xcb_io.c:179: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq' failed.